# Knockout.js: Binding to complex object

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockout.js and am trying to bind to the following object representing a user:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Locations": {
                "$id": "3",
                "$values": []
            },
            "Photos": {
                "$id": "4",
                "$values": []
            },
            "UserId": 1,
            "Name": "Test User"
        }
    ]
}
```

A user can zero or more locations, and zero or more photos.

The view model:

```
function UsersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray();

    var baseUri = 'http://localhost:46241/api/users';

    $.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
        self.users = data;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new UsersViewModel());
})
```

The HTML contains the following binding:

```
<ul id="update-users" data-bind="foreach: users"> 
     <li> 
            <div><div class="item">User ID</div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.UserId" />
            </div>                 
            <div><div class="item">Name</div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.Name" />
            </div>                  
     </li> 
</ul>
```

Am I flat out doing this incorrectly?  Or are user's object references to Locations and Photos possibly messing up the binding?

Comment: UserId and Name come under the "$values" part of the object - which you're not including in your binding. The fact that $values begins with a $ might get you in trouble with knockout. If you have control of how the object is generated, it would be worth getting rid of the  $'s to tidy it up a bit.

Comment: Is your self.users = data working fine? I do not see writing the $values array into your observable array

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Am I flat out doing this incorrectly?

Yes. You are overwriting your `observableArray` in the JSON callback, thus destroying it:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
    self.users = data;
});
```

In general, knockout observables are assigned to like this:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
    self.users(data.$values);
});
```

*Note that in your case, `data.$values` seems to contain the actual array, not `data` itself.*

This would work for your case, but it's not using knockout to its full potential.

The [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) has been created for exactly this case. It recursively traverses a complex object and turns all its properties into observables and all contained arrays into observable arrays. This gives you fine-grained control over the state of the object, allowing you to monitor every change.

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.$values, {}, self.users);
});
```

It also allows partial updates: Assume you retrieve a list of users from the server and your view model already has half of them. The mapping plugin is capable of adding only those to your view model that are missing and making appropriate changes to the existing ones. Read the ["Advanced usage" section](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced_usage) in the docs if you want to know how.

---

Assuming you get an array of user objects from the server and use the mapping plugin, then your binding would look like this:

```html
<ul id="update-users" data-bind="foreach: users"> 
     <li> 
            <div><div class="item">User ID</div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: UserId" />
            </div>                 
            <div><div class="item">Name</div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
            </div>
            <ul class="photos" data-bind="foreach: Photos.$values">
              <!-- ... -->
            <ul>
     </li> 
</ul>
```

On a general note, @Greg Smith's comment is correct. Try to lose the `$` in the object keys, they might clash with special variables in knockout at some point. You could safely replace them with underscores, for example.

On a more general note, I'd try to strip out the whole `$id`/`$values` notion in your JSON if I were you, it does not seem to serve any purpose:

```
[
    {
        "Locations": [],
        "Photos": [],
        "UserId": 1,
        "Name": "Test User"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps alot.  I will check out the mapping plugin, which looks to do a lot of heavy lifting.  As for the formatting of the json, this is what is being generated by JSON.NET from Entity Framework object.  How would I go about stripping out the $id/$values formatting?

Comment: @verbose I don't know, but this is good material for another question. It even seems that nobody had asked this before.